# How to fix "Connection refused error" when running a cluster mode spark job

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, slurm, terasort

I am running terasort benchmark with spark on the uni cluster which uses SLURM job management system. It works fine when I use --master local[8], however when I set the master as my current node I get connection refused error.

I run this command to launch the app on local without problem:

```
> spark-submit \
    --class com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraGen \
    --master local[8] \
    target/spark-terasort-1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 1g \
    data/terasort_in
```

When I use cluster mode I get the following error:

```
> spark-submit \
    --class com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraGen \
    --master spark://iris-055:7077 \ #name of the cluster-node in use
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --executor-memory 20G \
    --total-executor-cores 24 \
    target/spark-terasort-1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 5g \
    data/terasort_in
```

Output:

```
WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:  Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at
org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226) 
    at 
.
.
./*many lines of timeout logs etc.*/
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
... 11 more
```

I expect the command to run smooth and terminate, but I cannot get over this connection error.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the cluster your are using ? Are you sure your master can find executor memory with 20GB available memory ?

Comment: @Nonontb Sure I can use the maximum memory which is around 128GB per node.

Comment: Well, If your id job started, you can access the executors tab and tell how many executors were allocated ? Teragen compute the number of rows per executors according to the parallelism. If executors are not allocated correctly, you may face some overloading on the executors/drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be not defining --conf variables. This could work out:

```
spark-submit \
    --class com.github.ehiggs.spark.terasort.TeraGen \
    --master spark://iris-055:7077 \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=4g \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=20g \
    --executor-memory 20g \
    --total-executor-cores 24 \
    target/spark-terasort-1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 5g \
    data/terasort_in
```